# How to write for loops in a "pythonic" way

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a "python-ic" way to write the following nested forloops with if statements:

```
nonelist = []

for i in testlist:
    for e in i:
        if e == None:
            nonelist.append(i)
```

Comment: Are you looking for advice on how to write nested loops or are you trying to solve a problem here?

Comment: Based on your code it looks like testList is a list of lists - Is that correct?

Comment: This would be a better question if you gave an example `testlist` value so we could actually run the code.  I see nothing wrong with the way you wrote the code, although I'll point out that you might get the same `i` value appended to `nonelist` multiple times if it contains multiple `None`s (but perhaps that never can happen with your actual data, or perhaps that's exactly what you want to happen in such cases).

Comment: For readability, I suggest you look at [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  List comprehensions are space efficient but are difficult to read.

Comment: @balderman yes, @ JohnS the code works, I just wanted to know if there was a way to write this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the specific application, there might be better logic.  However, for your abstract problem, you'd be more Pythonic using a direct construction: the *list comprehension".

```
nonelist = [i for i in testlist if any([e is None for e in i]) ]
```

This isn't *quite* the same as your code: if there are multiple `None` values in `i`, then your code appends `i` for each occurrence; mine adds it only once.

@Austin's improvement:

```
nonelist = [i for i in testlist if None in i]
```

Comment: *"...mine adds it only once"*. In that case, how about just `nonelist = [i for i in testlist if None in i]`?

Comment: That's much better!  [head-slap].

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a flat iterator using `itertools.chain` and check items from there whether they are `None`:

```
[i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(testlist) if i is None]
```

**Example:**

```
In [389]: testlist = [[1, 2, 3, None], [4, 5, None, None]]                                                                                                                                                  

In [390]: [i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(testlist) if i is None]                                                                                                                                 
Out[390]: [None, None, None]
```

FWIW `None` is singleton, so you should use identity (`is`) test on them instead of eqality test (`==`).